# Opening percentage on Flex Accordion

Tags: apache-flex, accordion

I'm currently developing a Flex application with an accordion containing 2 canvas: one of them containing a DataGrid and the other one a form.
When the user clicks on one of the DataGrid's rows, it opens the accordion on the second (form) canvas. However, I'd like to open the second part of the accordion only by half, so they can still see the data in de datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an accordion is capable of this. I think accordions are just a viewstacks with a nifty hide/show effect. You are probably going to have to develop something very customized for this. Use your canvases, modify their heights and use a change effect. You will be able to get the view you are looking for and the nifty slide effect.

~Mike
ps: I say "I think" and "probably" a lot cause I'm pretty new to Flex